# Inno Setup - Conditional DisableDirPage

Tags: installation, inno-setup

Using Inno Setup 5.5.2 I am trying to conditionally skip selection of the installation directory depending on the existence of a path.  Specifically, if the 'D:\' drive is available I want installation to it in a predefined location with no prompts, and if it is not available, provide prompts with a reasonable default.

I have code that works for `DefaultDirName`, but not for `DisableDirPage`:

```
[Code]
const 
   DefaultDrive = 'D:\';
   AppFolder = 'SomeDir';

function GetDefaultDir( Param: String ) : String;
begin
   if DirExists( DefaultDrive ) then begin
      Result := DefaultDrive + AppFolder;
   end else begin
      Result := ExpandConstant('{pf}\') + AppFolder;
   end;
end;

function DefaultDirValid( Param: String ) : Boolean;
begin
   Result := DirExists( DefaultDrive );
end;

[Setup]
; Works as expected
DefaultDirName={code:GetDefaultDir}

...

; Compiler Error - Value of [Setup] section directive "DisableDirPage" is invalid.
DisableDirPage={code:DefaultDirValid}
```

I have tried using functions for `DisableDirPage` that return Strings of 'yes' and 'no', as well as Integers of 0 and 1.  I have also tried inlining the call to `DirExists`. All have produced the same compiler error.

My best guess is that it has something to do with the fact that `DisableDirPage` takes a tri-state yes, no, or auto.  Is there a specific type associated with the tri-state logic that needs to be returned?  The Inno Help on [Scripted Constants](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) only says:

> The called function must have 1 String parameter named Param, and must return a String or a Boolean value depending on where the constant is used.

Comment: That's the task for `ShouldSkipPage` event handler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the [`ShouldSkipPage`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=ShouldSkipPage) event handler you can skip the directory selection page when the `DefaultDrive` constant path exists with the following script:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={code:GetDefaultDir}

[Code]
const 
  DefaultDrive = 'D:\';
  AppFolder = 'Some Folder';

function GetDefaultDir(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := DefaultDrive + AppFolder;
  if not DirExists(DefaultDrive) then
    Result := ExpandConstant('{pf}\') + AppFolder;
end;

function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (PageID = wpSelectDir) and DirExists(DefaultDrive);
end;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks!  Out of curiosity, is there any way to code a response for DisableDirPage, or is it simply forbidden since the ShouldSkipPage event handler exists?

Comment: Good question, from a quick test trying to use `string` as a result type of your `DefaultDirValid` function the compiler failed with invalid value, so it's probably forbidden.

Comment: Generally constants only work on those settings that take string values (and are only used at runtime).  Most boolean settings don't support code functions as a result, but there are usually alternatives.

Comment: @Miral, agree, but [`DisableDirPage`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_disabledirpage) is not a boolean directive. It accepts 3 possible values what was the reason why I've tried to return string to it.

Comment: It was originally a boolean directive, and now it's a small-enum directive.  Same thing basically; it just gets encoded into bitflags in the final installer, so there's nowhere it can store constants.  Besides, that's what `ShouldSkipPage` is for.